# How to constrain div drag space? (no jQuery)

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, draggable, border-layout

I would like to constrain the movement of a draggable `div` within another `div`; this is accomplished by the code below:

```html
  <script src="https://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
  <style>
  #modalPar { width: 300px; height: 150px; padding: 0.5em; border: 1px solid black}
  #myModal {width: 200px; border: 1px solid black}
  </style>
  <script>
  $(function() {
    $("#modalPar").draggable();
    $("#myModal").draggable({containment: "parent"});});
</script>

<div id="modalPar">Parent
<div id="myModal">Child</div></div>
```

I'd like to accomplish the same without jQuery. Tried the approach below:

```js
dragElement(document.getElementById("myModal"));

function dragElement(elmnt) {
  var pos1 = 0, pos2 = 0, pos3 = 0, pos4 = 0;
  if (document.getElementById(elmnt.id + "header")) {
  document.getElementById(elmnt.id + "header").onmousedown = dragMouseDown;} 
  else {elmnt.onmousedown = dragMouseDown;}

  function dragMouseDown(w) {
    w = w || window.event;
    w.preventDefault();
    pos3 = w.clientX;
    pos4 = w.clientY;
    document.onmouseup = closeDragElement;
    document.onmousemove = elementDrag;}
    
  function elementDrag(w) {
    w = w || window.event;
    w.preventDefault();
    pos1 = pos3 - w.clientX;
    pos2 = pos4 - w.clientY;
    pos3 = w.clientX;
    pos4 = w.clientY;
    elmnt.style.top = (elmnt.offsetTop - pos2) + "px";
    elmnt.style.left = (elmnt.offsetLeft - pos1) + "px";}

  function closeDragElement() {
    document.onmouseup = null;
    document.onmousemove = null;}}
```

```css
#myModal {
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 9;
    background-color: #f1f1f1;
    text-align: center;
    border: 1px solid #d3d3d3;
    top: 0; right: 0; width: 110px; height: 160px}
#myModalheader {
    padding: 10px;
    cursor: move;
    z-index: 10;
    background-color: #2196F3;
    color: #fff;}
```

```html
<div id="myModal">
  <div id="myModalheader">Click here to move</div>
  <p>Move</p><p>this</p><p>DIV</p>
</div>
```

The div can be dragged by the dragging header, which is contained within the full div being dragged, but overflows the parent div. How can this be prevented with JavaScript?

Help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an option; I can't propose that this is as robust or browser compatible as jQuery, but it should show the general idea. I'm using a handle variable, `dragged`, and used a couple of classes to distinguish `draggable` and `draggable-child` elements. There's a simple bounds check for children. It's quite tweakable for padding and other things you'd like to take into consideration.

```js
let dragged;

document.addEventListener("mouseup", e => dragged = null);
document.addEventListener("mousedown", e => {
  if (e.target.classList.contains("draggable-handle")) {
    dragged = e.target.parentElement;
  }
});

document.addEventListener("mousemove", e => {    
  if (dragged) {
    e.preventDefault();
    const x = +(dragged.style.left.match(/-?\d+/g) || 0) + e.movementX;
    const y = +(dragged.style.top.match(/-?\d+/g) || 0) + e.movementY;
    const w = dragged.getBoundingClientRect().width;
    const h = dragged.getBoundingClientRect().height;

    if (dragged.classList.contains("draggable-child")) {
      const r = dragged.parentElement.getBoundingClientRect();
      const pw = r.width;
      const ph = r.height;

      if (x < 0 || y < 0 || x + w >= pw || y + h >= ph) {
        return;
      }
    }

    dragged.style.top = `${y}px`;
    dragged.style.left = `${x}px`;
  }
});
```

```css
#modalPar {
  width: 300px;
  height: 150px;
  border: 1px solid black
}

#myModal {
  width: 200px;
  height: 100px;
  border: 1px solid black
}

.draggable, .draggable-child, .draggable-handle {
  position: absolute;
}

.draggable-handle {
  padding: 0.3em;
  background: black;
  color: white;
  cursor: grab;
}
```

```html
<div id="modalPar" class="draggable">
  <div class="draggable draggable-handle">[drag]</div>
  <div id="myModal" class="draggable draggable-child">
    <div class="draggable draggable-handle">[drag]</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Works great for the exact example, though I'm unable to apply it in my full context; I seek to drag the child by clicking an icon inside the child div, as here: https://jsfiddle.net/bd41jy5L/38/ Any tweaks to have it work this way?

Comment: Handles added. I recommend posting your full requirements when possible.

Comment: Works well enough - though encountered several problems in my use which'll likely take some time to address; going to proceed with jQuery. Thanks for your input.

Comment: Yeah, no need to reinvent the wheel on this one--I take it as a fun exercise. Good luck.